# Force Logout of user on multiple devices using JWT

Tags: rest, authentication, jwt

We have an existing REST API that is currently using JWT.

Client came with the requirement that users can only use 1 device at a time. For example, if user logs in from iOS device then logs in Android device, then the iOS device should be "forced" to logout.

Since we are using JWT, we are not keeping track of tokens, except a Token Blacklist when user click Log Out.

I researched on how to "force" log out the user and it seems we would need to keep track of the last token used by the user, then invalidate that once we detect a new log-in.

Is there no cleaner / alternative way to achieve above?

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps to implement your requirement:

**step 1: save the timestamp of last user activity performed for password update or logout from all device**

1. add a column `lastSessionResetDate` to store last password update date in your user table
2. While performing forget password/change password apis or at logout-from-all-device, update `lastSessionResetDate`

**step 2: set `lastSessionResetDate` in JWT Claims, when generating JWT token**

example of setting claim while token generation

```
//make a claims map (`Claim extends Map<String, Object>`)
Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        claims.put(CLAIM_KEY_USERNAME, user.getUserName());
        claims.put(CLAIM_KEY_AUDIENCE, "web");
        claims.put(CLAIM_KEY_CREATED, new Date());
        claims.put(CLAIM_KEY_LAST_SESSION_RESET, user.lastSessionResetDate());

//set claims and build JWT
return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(user.getUserName())
.setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
.setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + yourTokenValidity))
.signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512,"yourSecretEncodedBase64")
.compact();
```

You can get any of claim value at time of parsing JWT token.

**Step 3: Time to validate user and session**
After getting User entity by JWT, check if `lastSessionResetDate` is valid till time, else unauthorized the request.
You must be already fetching user from database, so you don't need to make any other query because our new added column `lastSessionResetDate` will be a part of the same query result. (You just have to add one if-else block).

**Note:** You can also get prompt value in response from users for `log-me-out-from-other-devices`

Hope you have got an idea, Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use JWTs as Bearer tokens, depending on your requirements, it might not be sufficient enough "to keep track of the last token used by the user, then invalidate that once we detect a new log-in.".

As Bearer tokens (independent on whether it's JWT or not) are send by the client, the client is also aware of the token, which allows the sender to also copy and paste tokens from one device to another (or issue requests including the same token from various devices).

Your requirements sound like a standard use case for proper session management that allows e.g. for user-agent binding.